# What does "levitate" mean this context?

Tags: car, terminology, front-wheel-drive

On this site here https://wuling.id/en/blog/autotips/fwd-vs-rwd-drive-system-whats-the-difference
I saw the phrase "FWD Vehicles cannot levitate, while RWD Vehicles are capable of levitating."
What exactly does that mean?

Comment: I suspect a translation error is the likely explanation here.

Comment: I was coming up with the same conclusion. RWD vehicles don't levitate ... closest I've seen a vehicle do that is ones which have hydraulic suspension which is made to raise and lower depending on the vehicle speed and terrain, but the tires never leave the ground.

Comment: They probably mean [do a wheelie](https://www.youtube.com/shorts/iAJUCD4X8pU), which you can't in a FWD car.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bad translation. Not levitate, but **DRIFT**.

I plugged the original Indonesian text into Google Translate and got this result:

> FWD vehicles are driven via the front wheels, while RWD vehicles are
> driven via the rear tires.
>
> The weight of FWD vehicles is lighter than RWD vehicles.
>
> The cabin for a RWD vehicle is usually more limited than for a FWD
> vehicle.
>
> Vehicles with a RWD drive system are more balanced than FWD.
>
> RWD vehicles have better handling than FWD vehicles.
>
> **FWD vehicles cannot drift, while RWD vehicles can drift.**
>
> RWD vehicles are more maneuverable on various terrains, while FWD
> vehicles are only suitable for driving on city streets.

Comment: Wow, you mean Google Translate actually came up with something comprehensible? That's amazing :o)